# Click to show submenu then hover to see other submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, menubar

I've been suck on this problem for a while. What I'm trying to do is when I click on a link on the menu bar, the sub menu shows up. Then If I hover over to the other link on the menu bar, the submenu for that link shows up and it closes the previous submenu open. Then when i click on the link again for the open submenu, it is supposed to close the submenu currently open.

What my code does now is that when i click on the link on the menu bar it opens the submenu. The submenu stays there until i click on the other link on the menu bar to close the existing submenu and open the submenu for the clicked item. To close the submenu, I click on the link that is associated with the submenu.

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id="index">
<div id="menu-bar">
    <ul class="menu-bar">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myLink" divId="about">About Me</a>
    <ul id="sub-menu" class="about">
    <li><a>something</a></li>
    <li><a>Filler</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="myLink" divId="resume">Resume</a>
    <ul id="sub-menu" class="resume">
    <li><a>Something</a></li>
    <li><a>Filler</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Contact Me</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p>Reactive</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
#index {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
}

#menu-bar {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 10px 0px 0px -10px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
   z-index: 12;
   float: left;
}

ul.menu-bar li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0px 0px 12px;
}

ul.menu-bar li ul#sub-menu {
    display: block;
    z-index: 12;
    padding-left: 1px;
    width: 825px;
} 

ul.menu-bar li ul#sub-menu {
    margin: -10px 0px 0px 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 0px;
}

#content {
   width: 800px;
   height 100%;
   float: left;
}
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
$("#sub-menu.about").hide();
$("#sub-menu.resume").hide();

var curId;
var prevId = "";
//when the link is clicked
$(".myLink").click(function(e){
    curId = $(this).attr('divId');
    if(prevId === curId){   //if same value is clicked toggle it
        $("#sub-menu."+curId).toggle();
        prevId = "";        //clear prevId to avoid confusion
    } else{
        if(prevId !== ""){ //if different value is clicked hide the previous ones
            $("#sub-menu."+prevId).hide();
        }
        $("#sub-menu."+curId).show();   //show the current one clicked
    }
    prevId = curId; //set prevId to clicked value for comparison
});

$(".myLink").hover(function(){
    if(prevId !== ""){
        curId = $(this).attr('divId');
        console.log("mouseover "+curId);
    }
},
function(){
    if(prevId !== ""){
        curId = $(this).attr('divId');
        console.log("mouseleave " +curId);
    }
});
```

I have also put the code on JS fiddle so please feel free to play around with it and give me some guidance.

http://jsfiddle.net/dcmeister/SmM4D/1/

Comment: your code is working fine ,what do u expect ?

Comment: and use full stop (.) . Use full stop ,and dont make Long 4 lines sentence. not getting ur question

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: Think of it this way, if you have used a mac or other software with top menu bars. I want my code to function like that. It is supposed to work where you click on the link and a submenu shows and you can hover to other links to see other submenus while the previous one closes. Right now i have to click the other menu bar link to close the submenu  and click to see the other submenu.